# How to read the text from the alert box using Python + Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, alert

I want to read the text from the alert box.

If this text is found in the alert box I have to close the alert box:

[image: Alert Box]

Comment: Do you have something? (Code)

Comment: @RatmirAsanov, alert = driver.switch_to_alert() I tried this

Comment: How would you do it in a non-automated environment? Is that an alert box or simply another element on the page that gets populated/visible on a certain condition? If it's a simple alert box, you could simply wait for it to appear, switch to it, get its text property and then dismiss it. If it's a div element, you might not be able to  access the text of an inner element directly and you might have to fetch its parent div first then iterate through that div's children searching for the proper element that houses your alert text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar situations as this in my framework as well, and this is how I solved it.

```
if (_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()[contains(.,'No Sales Found')]")).Enabled)
{
     //Do Something
}
```

Put this after functionality that may bring the error up. Also, this example is using C# and _driver as the driver, which may be different from what you are using.

Answer (score 8):

To  read the text from the *Alert Box*, validate and close the *Alert* you have to switch to the *Alert* first and follow the below mentioned steps:

```
alert = chrome.switch_to_alert()
alert_text = alert.text
# validate the alert text
alert.accept()
```

However, now it seems [`switch_to_alert()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_alert) is **deprecated**. So as per the current implementation you need to use:

- [**`switch_to.alert()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) as follows:

  ```
  alert = driver.switch_to.alert()
  alert_text = alert.text
  # validate the alert text
  alert.accept()
  ```
- As per best practices you should always induce *WebDriverWait* for the [alert_is_present()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.alert_is_present) before switching to an **Alert** as follows:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # other lines of code
  alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present)
  alert_text = alert.text
  # validate the alert text
  alert.accept()
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Why switching to alert through selenium is not stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839355/why-switching-to-alert-through-selenium-is-not-stable/48839525#48839525)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should switch to the alert window:

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
```

Then get the text on the alert window by using `alert.text`. And check your text for correctness.

Then do such action (close the alert window):

```
alert.accept()
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know python but in java you can like this:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
String msg=alert.getText();
if(msg.equals("Message you compare"))
{
alert.accept();
}
```