# Why switching to alert through selenium is not stable?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Why switching to alert through selenium is not stable?

For example.
1. Run a code and all good.  Everything worked out well.
But if this code is run in a few minutes, then there may be errors.
There is no element you can click on, for example. And so on.
2. On one site there is an alert window.

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.dismiss()
```

So I close it. But he works through time. All is well, then errors.

```
for al in range(3):
    try:
        alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert.dismiss()
        time.sleep(randint(1, 3))
    except:
        pass
```

I wrote and everything works out as it should.
But I think that this is not beautiful.
Why is everything so unstable?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are there multiple alerts? Multiple tabs? What exactly stops working if you just dismiss the alert once? Perhaps you need to explicitly switch back to the main window/tab.

Comment: Please provide an example of complete code which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, i.e., [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your second part is a bit confusing. *Everything works but it's not beautiful* implies a different question.

Comment: Selenium should only be used for testing not scraping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your code block there are a couple of issues which you need to address as follows :

- [*Switching to an Alert*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.alert.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.alert) : The method `switch_to_alert()` is **Deprecated** and you should be using **`switch_to.alert`** instead. The API Docs clearly mentions the following :

  ```
   def switch_to_alert(self):
       """ Deprecated use driver.switch_to.alert
       """
       warnings.warn("use driver.switch_to.alert instead", DeprecationWarning)
       return self._switch_to.alert
  ```
- [*Wait for the Alert to be present*](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.alert_is_present) : You should always induce *WebDriverWait* for the *Alert* to be **present** before invoking `accept()` or `dismiss()` as follows :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present).dismiss()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This will click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button on the alert:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

This will click the <kbd>CANCEL</kbd> button on the alert:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()
```