# Can not get text with Selenium from web-browser alert pop-up

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, text, alert, webdriverwait

Some website may ask me different questions with pop-up alerts.

I can catch them with `Selenium (python)`. But **can not** see their text.
I tried

```
an_alert_object = driver.switch_to.alert
```

and

```
an_alert_object = selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert(driver)
```

and

```
an_alert_object = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
```

I do always avoid `NoAlertPresentException`

I can do

```
an_alert_object.accept()
```

in any way.

But I never can get `an_alert_object.text` it is always empty. Why?
What am I doing wrong ? How can I get the text of an alert (actually it is confirm box)?

Comment: the Alert type should have a getText() method... try with an_alert_object.getText();  (and maybe cast it as Alert type... Alert an_alert_object = ...)

Comment: @pcalkins: `.getText` is in `Java bindings`, `.text` is right method for Python.

Comment: to OP: Show us how does it look like? maybe through screenshot or Weburl, also can you inspect that `confirmed box` ?

Comment: Both .getText() and .get_text() cause
AttributeError: 'Alert' object has no attribute 'getText'/'get_text'
python doesn't have them

Comment: I'd be glad to inspect these alerts (confirm boxes) but I don't know how. What would you lke to see with screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

Before you attempt to get the text you need to switch to the [*Alert*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839355/why-switching-to-alert-through-selenium-is-not-stable/48839525#48839525) first:

```
alert = driver.switch_to.alert()
```

Preferably inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*alert_is_present()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859356/how-to-click-the-ok-button-within-an-alert-using-python-selenium/61859592#61859592) and extract the text as follows:

```
alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
time.sleep(3)
alert_text = alert.text
```

---

### Referances

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to read the text from the alert box using Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074558/how-to-read-the-text-from-the-alert-box-using-python-selenium/47075168#47075168)

Comment: Of course, I did it. I mentioned it in my first example.

Comment: I have just tried

```an_alert_object = driver.switch_to.alert
an_alert_object = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
print(an_alert_object.text)```

and got empty alert text again.

Comment: @C4H7Cl2O4P Can you add a sleep in between as per the answer update?

Comment: When I use (EC.alert_is_present) instead of (EC.alert_is_present()  ) I get

<class 'TypeError'>, TypeError('__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'), <traceback object at 0x7fe0b0ad5400>

Comment: @C4H7Cl2O4P That was a typo, corrected.

Comment: I do. I rotate it in loop with time.sleep(1)
Alert is ready in very first run but every loop turn alert.text is empty. But I see the text in the confirm box.