# How can I get the text from an temporary alert using chromedriver Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I'm writing a program to automatically book a desk in my library using chromedriver. I'm looping through all seats looking for one that isn't booked already, then using

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath).click()
```

on both starting and ending time to book the seat.
After clicking, there can be different alerts that can pop up, confirming the booking or pointing out an issue. These alerts disappear after a few seconds. I'm trying to use the text of the pop up to verify whether the booking has been successful or not.

So far, I've tried this:

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present)
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    text = alert.text
    if "some Text" in text:
        print("Booking successful")
    elif "some other text" in text:
        print("booking not successful")
except:
    print("no alert")
```

However, the alert does not get recognized, I always get "no alert".

This is how the alerts looks like:

```
<div data-notify="container" class="col-xs-11 col-sm-4 alert alert-success animated fadeInDown" role="alert" data-notify-position="top-center" style="display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; position: fixed; transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out 0s; z-index: 5000; top: 20px; left: 0px; right: 0px;">
    <button type="button" aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-notify="dismiss" style="position: absolute; right: 10px; top: 5px; z-index: 5002;"> × </button>
    <span data-notify="icon"> </span>
    <span data-notify="title"></span>
    <span data-notify="message"> Booking successful. </span>
    <a href="#" target="_blank" data-notify="url"> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like a DOM element with a bunch of extra whitespace in it, not an [alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) looks like an [alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859356/how-to-click-the-ok-button-within-an-alert-using-python-selenium/61859592#61859592) due to the presence of classnames like *`alert`*, *`alert-success`*, etc. But it's not an actual [alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47074558/how-to-read-the-text-from-the-alert-box-using-python-selenium/47075168#47075168)

To print the text *Booking successful.* from the *alert* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='alert'][data-notify='container'] span[data-notify='message']").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'alert') and @data-notify='container']//span[@data-notify='message']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='alert'][data-notify='container'] span[data-notify='message']"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'alert') and @data-notify='container']//span[@data-notify='message']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)